# How do I integrate $\sqrt{1+\sec2x}$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I tried converting $\sec 2x$ into $1/\cos 2x$, and then performing further simplification which led me to $$\int \sqrt{\frac2{1-\tan^2 x}} dx$$

I'm unable to take it from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I=\int\sqrt{1+\sec2x}\ \mathrm dx$$
As has been already been noted, 
$$\sqrt{1+\sec2x}=\frac{\sqrt2|\cos x|}{\sqrt{1-2\sin^2x}}$$
Hence we substitute $t=\sqrt2\sin x$,
$$I=\int\frac{\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$
We now substitute $t=\sin u$:
$$I=\int\frac{\cos u}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2u}}\mathrm du$$
$$I=\int\frac{\cos u}{\sqrt{\cos^2u}}\mathrm du$$
$$I=\int\mathrm du$$
$$I=u$$
$$I=\arcsin t$$
$$I=\arcsin\big(\sqrt2\sin x\big)+C$$

Answer (score 2):

It is $$\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$$ so you will get $$\frac{2\cos^2(x)}{2\cos^2(x)-1}$$,now use the tan-half angle substitution.

Comment: See here for further explanations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\sqrt{1+\sec2x}=\dfrac{\sqrt2|\cos x|}{\sqrt{1-2\sin^2x}}$$

Substitute $\sqrt2\sin x=y$